# cannot be held responsible for responsibility or accountability, hold harmless - single word request

Tags: single-word-requests

In the context of being held responsible or accountable for your words, is there a single word that describes a being without accountability or responsibility?

Specifically, the state of always being held harmless for anything they say because of their job position, say a comedian or an entertainer.

Comment: Responsibility, accountability, and holding harmless someone are three different things. Which one do you want? Why do you think a comedian is protected from these [suites](http://theweek.com/articles/467899/5-comedians-who-sued-over-material)?

Comment: @PhilSweet In the link you supplied, two of the cases were dismissed and the others do not detail any sort of retribution paid to the plaintiff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious word is simply **[unaccountable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unaccountable)**:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> 2 : not to be called to account : not responsible

The only other single word I can think of—although it has a broader meaning than you might like—is

[**Exempt**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exempt):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : free or released from some liability or requirement to which others are subject • was *exempt* from jury duty • the estate was *exempt* from taxes

Of course, there are also some very specific contextual phrases. For instance, **diplomatic immunity**.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to express this would be to say that the entity in question is **not liable** — that is to say, they have no legal accountability. There are some instances of people using the word **non-liable** to convey the same meaning.